# What is にゃんちゅう saying here?

Tags: grammar, words, listening

[image]

In [this NHK video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PqpnYjxRqqA&t=114s), あいちゃん seem to be demonstrating some cooking skills, while a cat named にゃんちゅう seems to be praising her by her side. I understand most of what he says, but there are 3 places (**bolded** below) in his speech where I cannot catch what he is saying even with a dictionary, and even by slowing down the video.

His speech starts 0:42, and ends 1:57. **The 3 places I have problems with have timestamps 0:54, 1:21 and 1:51**. My attempts, after many listens, are below. In addition, I suspect 0:54 is a variation of ～でなくてなんであろう, but I am not sure what it is. Could I receive some help for these three areas?

> にゃんちゅう：もんにちは！今日はあいちゃんが日頃より鍛えたお料理の腕前をお見せします！では、あい先生、どうぞ！
>
> あいちゃん：こんにちは！今日は私の得意料理を皆さんにお教えしたいと思います。
>   助手のにゃんちゅうくん、よろしくね。
>
> にゃんちゅう：はい、先生。では、おこちらに、先生に腕を振るっていただく、材料。すでに用意されております。ハハ。よろしくお願い致します！
>
> あいちゃん：よろしくおねがいします。
>
> にゃんちゅう：おっと！いきなり豆腐を持った！おっ、これを包丁で切るんだにゃ！包丁が入った！繊細な手の動き、いかがでしょう、みにゃさん！神経がすみずみに**まぜいきわたった包丁＿＿＿、これを芸術＿＿＿** (0:54) なんと申しましょうか！できたぞ！これは、さいの目切りだ。お見事です！
>
> にゃんちゅう：さ、そして、つぎのお料理に参りましょう。二品目はいったい、なんでしょうか？二品目は、おっ！これだにゃ、これは、日本が **運が世界の一品嘔吐、** (1:21) 納豆！では、お願いします！おっ！ごらんください！このしなやかな手の動き、納豆をねばねばに掻き回しております！そして、おっと！なめらかなこの回転、回転技だ！さすがの納豆も、あい先生に混ぜてもらい、 **さくやうれさによろこびのかいをあげてる** (1:51) にちがいありません！以上！

Edited: ちょっと to おっと, before いきなり

Comment: 「ちょっと！いきなり豆腐を持った！」のところは「おっと！いきなり豆腐を持った！」ですね

Comment: ありがとうございます。変えります～

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「神経がすみずみに**まぜ**いきわたった包丁＿＿＿、これを芸術＿＿＿ (0:54) なんと申しましょうか！」

↓

> 「神経がすみずみに**まで**行きわたった包丁**さばき**、これを芸術**と言わずして**なんと申しましょうか！」

「日本が **運が**世界の一品**嘔吐**」　Why would he say "barf" here?

↓

> 「日本が生{う}んだ世界{せかい}の一品{いっぴん}、おーっと、」　「おーっと」 is an exclamation.

「 **さくや**うれ**さ**によろこびの**かい**をあげてる 」

↓

> 「**さぞや**嬉{うれ}しさに喜{よろこ}びの声{こえ}をあげている」

Comment: ありがとうございました！とても勉強になります。

Comment: 「日本が生んだ世界の一品」で一旦終わっている。だから "、"ではなく "。"が来るべき。

Answer (score 1):

神経が隅々にまで行き渡った包丁さばき、これを芸術と言わずして何と申しましょうか～！？

これは、日本が生んだ世界の一品・・・おっと！納豆！

さぁぞぉや（さすが？？？Maybe. Or maybe さあ、後は）嬉しさに喜びの声を上げているに違いありません。

Comment: Oh, I just saw the person above's answer. I didn't know さぞや was a word. lol     Also, the 嘔吐 after 一品 is just an exclamation おっと！ because the natto stinks

Comment: Thanks! I really thought the natto made him want to 嘔吐, oops